# Convert nested XML content into CSV using xml tree in python

Tags: python, xml, csv, dictionary, xml-parsing

I'm very new to python and please treat me as same. When i tried to convert the XML content into List of Dictionaries I'm getting output but not as expected and tried a lot playing around.

XML Content

```
<project>
<data>
    <row>
        <respondent>m0wxo5f6w42h3fot34m7s6xij</respondent>
        <timestamp>10-06-16 11:30</timestamp>
        <product>1</product>
        <replica>1</replica>
        <seqnr>1</seqnr>
        <session>1</session>
        <column>
            <question>Q1</question>
            <answer>a1</answer>
        </column>
        <column>
            <question>Q2</question>
            <answer>a2</answer>
        </column>
    </row>
<row>
        <respondent>w42h3fot34m7s6x</respondent>
        <timestamp>10-06-16 11:30</timestamp>
        <product>1</product>
        <replica>1</replica>
        <seqnr>1</seqnr>
        <session>1</session>
        <column>
            <question>Q3</question>
            <answer>a3</answer>
        </column>
        <column>
            <question>Q4</question>
            <answer>a4</answer>
        </column>
    <column>
            <question>Q5</question>
            <answer>a5</answer>
        </column>
    </row>
</data>
</project>
```

Code i have used:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(xml_file.xml)   # import xml from
root = tree.getroot()  
data_list = []

for item in root.find('./data'):    # find all projects node
  data = {}              # dictionary to store content of each projects
  for child in item:
    data[child.tag] = child.text   # add item to dictionary

#-----------------for loop with subchild is not working as expcted in my case
    for subchild in child:
      data[subchild.tag] = subchild.text
      data_list.append(data)
print(data_list)

headers = {k for d in data_list for k in d.keys()} # headers for csv 
with open(csv_file,'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = headers)    # creating a DictWriter object
    writer.writeheader()    # write headers to csv
    writer.writerows(data_list)
```

Output for the data_list is getting the last info of question to the list of dictionaries.
i guess the issue is at subchild forloop but im not understanding how to append the list with dictionaries.

```
[{
  'respondent': 'anonymous_m0wxo5f6w42h3fot34m7s6xij',
  'timestamp': '10-06-16 11:30',
  'product': '1',
  'replica': '1',
  'seqnr': '1',
  'session': '1',
  'column': '\n  ,
  'question': 'Q2',
  'answer': 'a2'
},
{
'respondent': 'w42h3fot34m7s6x',
  'timestamp': '10-06-16 11:30',
  'product': '1',
  'replica': '1',
  'seqnr': '1',
  'session': '1',
  'column': '\n ,
  'question': 'Q2',
  'answer': 'a2'
}.......
]
```

I expect the below output, tried a lot but unable to loop over the column tag.

```
[{
    'respondent': 'anonymous_m0wxo5f6w42h3fot34m7s6xij',
    'timestamp': '10-06-16 11:30',
    'product': '1',
    'replica': '1',
    'seqnr': '1',
    'session': '1',
    'question': 'Q1',
    'answer': 'a1'
  },
  {
    'respondent': 'anonymous_m0wxo5f6w42h3fot34m7s6xij',
    'timestamp': '10-06-16 11:30',
    'product': '1',
    'replica': '1',
    'seqnr': '1',
    'session': '1',
    'question': 'Q2',
    'answer': 'a2'
  },
  {
    'respondent': 'w42h3fot34m7s6x',
    'timestamp': '10-06-16 11:30',
    'product': '1',
    'replica': '1',
    'seqnr': '1',
    'session': '1',
    'question': 'Q3',
    'answer': 'a3'
  },
  {
    'respondent': 'w42h3fot34m7s6x',
    'timestamp': '10-06-16 11:30',
    'product': '1',
    'replica': '1',
    'seqnr': '1',
    'session': '1',
    'question': 'Q4',
    'answer': 'a4'
  },
  {
    'respondent': 'w42h3fot34m7s6x',
    'timestamp': '10-06-16 11:30',
    'product': '1',
    'replica': '1',
    'seqnr': '1',
    'session': '1',
    'question': 'Q5',
    'answer': 'a5'
  }
]
```

I have refereed so many stack overflow questions on xml tree but still didn't helped me.

any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is this question related to [this previous one of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805355/convert-xml-to-list-of-dictionaries-in-python) ?

Comment: No this is new  question, where i need to loop over on the sub child of the root to make a list of dictionaries and convert it to CSV. i have referred few stackoverflow but nowhere i found how to loop.

Comment: Alright, then can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Comment: I need to convert the row tag dependent information into csv, i know how to convert but im not understanding how to get the nested tag('project/data/row/column') information together as shown in expected output. Please help

Comment: _im not understanding how to get the nested tag('project/data/row/column') information together as shown in expected output._ That's the part we need more information about. As you're working to do that, you hit a wall at some point, right? What is that wall?

Comment: @AMC i have edited the question. i think the issue is at subchild for loop. Hope you understand the issue better now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Coding aside, are you sure the output is what you want? You have 2 users with 2 and 3 questions each, so you are creating 10 dictionaries with most of the information replicated. Why not create just two nested subdictionaries, one for each user, just like the xml?

Comment: @JackFleeting yes, i need the output as shown in the expected. The reason why i need such a way is when i convert it into CSV, i need all the supportive information for question and answer.

Comment: And I'm trying to get total 5 dictionaries only for each user with there respective questions and answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem understanding what this code is supposed to do because it uses abstract variable names like `item`, `child`, `subchild` and this makes it hard to reason about the code. I'm not as clever as that, so I renamed the variables to `row`, `tag`, and `column` to make it easier for me to see what the code is doing. (In my book, even *row* and *column* are a bit abstract, but I suppose the opacity of the XML input is hardly your fault.)

You have 2 rows but you want 5 dictionaries, because you have 5 `<column>` tags and you want each `<column>`'s data in a separate dictionary. But you want the *other* tags in the `<row>` to be repeated along with each `<column>`'s data.

That means you need to build a dictionary for every `<row>`, then, for each `<column>`, *add* that column's data to the dictionary, then output it before going on to the next column.

This code makes the simplifying assumption that all of your `<columns>`s have the same structure, with exactly one `<question>` and exactly one `<answer>` and nothing else. If this assumption does not hold then a `<column>` may get reported with stale data it inherited from the previous `<column>` in the same row. It will also produce no output at all for any `<row>` that does not have at least one `<column>`.

The code has to loop through the tags twice, once for the non-`<column>`s and once for the `<column>`s. Otherwise it can't be sure it has seen all the non-`<column>` tags before it starts outputting the `<column>`s.

There are other (no doubt more elegant) ways to do this, but I kept the code structure as close to your original as I could, other than making the variable names less opaque.

```
for row in root.find('./data'):    # find all projects node
    data = {}              # dictionary to store content of each projects
    for tag in row:
        if tag.tag != "column":
            data[tag.tag] = tag.text   # add row to dictionary
    # Now the dictionary data is built for the row level
    for tag in row:
        if tag.tag == "column":
            for column in tag:
                data[column.tag] = column.text
            # Now we have added the column level data for one column tag
            data_list.append(data.copy())
```

Output is as below. The key order of the dicts isn't preserved because I used `pprint.pprint` for convenience.

```
[{'answer': 'a1',
  'product': '1',
  'question': 'Q1',
  'replica': '1',
  'respondent': 'm0wxo5f6w42h3fot34m7s6xij',
  'seqnr': '1',
  'session': '1',
  'timestamp': '10-06-16 11:30'},
 {'answer': 'a2',
  'product': '1',
  'question': 'Q2',
  'replica': '1',
  'respondent': 'm0wxo5f6w42h3fot34m7s6xij',
  'seqnr': '1',
  'session': '1',
  'timestamp': '10-06-16 11:30'},
 {'answer': 'a3',
  'product': '1',
  'question': 'Q3',
  'replica': '1',
  'respondent': 'w42h3fot34m7s6x',
  'seqnr': '1',
  'session': '1',
  'timestamp': '10-06-16 11:30'},
 {'answer': 'a4',
  'product': '1',
  'question': 'Q4',
  'replica': '1',
  'respondent': 'w42h3fot34m7s6x',
  'seqnr': '1',
  'session': '1',
  'timestamp': '10-06-16 11:30'},
 {'answer': 'a5',
  'product': '1',
  'question': 'Q5',
  'replica': '1',
  'respondent': 'w42h3fot34m7s6x',
  'seqnr': '1',
  'session': '1',
  'timestamp': '10-06-16 11:30'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and it looks great. As im very new to pythonic ways and do's, from next time i will take care to explain better. when i have executed the above code, im facing an issue that in each dictionary in the list for the question and answer its getting updated with last iterated value (Q2 and a2). Can you please share the output

Comment: Output added. The misbehaviour you report was due to careless cut'n'paste on my part.